# devtools::install_github error " unexpected section header '\description'" R

Tags: r, github

I created a R package using `devtools` and `roxygen2`. When I build the package using check() no warnings, errors, or notes appear.  I have the package stored on github in a private rep.  When I try to install the package from gihub using `devtools::install_github` I receive the following error:

```
    Error : (converted from warning)
C:/Users/melissa.buechlein/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp2Bz94o/R.INSTALL1a27c6f823faa/WoodAERMODpackage/man/plot_line_lineq_stats.Rd:69: unexpected section header '\description'
    ERROR: installing Rd objects failed for package 'WoodAERMODpackage'
    * removing 'C:/Users/melissa.buechlein/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/WoodAERMODpackage'
    * restoring previous 'C:/Users/melissa.buechlein/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/WoodAERMODpackage'
    Error: Failed to install 'WoodAERMODpackage' from GitHub:
      (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/MELISS~1.BUE/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpU5bvft/file18ec847097238/WoodAERMODpackage_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

This is the specific file with the issue according to the error (this is the function as stored in the /man/ folder)

```
% Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
% Please edit documentation in R/plot_line_lineq_stats.R
\name{plot_line_lineq_stats}
\alias{plot_line_lineq_stats}
\title{linear line plots}
\usage{
plot_line_lineq_stats(
  df,
  x_label,
  y_label,
  color_label,
  stats_loc = "center",
  color_palette = "Spectral",
  headers = c("x", "y", "rows", "columns", "color_bin"),
  scales_qualifier = "fixed",
  max_ncol = 6,
  max_nrow = 6,
  set_nrow = NULL,
  set_ncol = NULL,
  start_date = min(df$x),
  end_date = max(df$x),
  breakS_min0r = "1 hour",
  Date_Label = "\%B \%d",
  plot_stats = c("'mean'", "function(z){quantile(z,0.25)}",
    "function(z){quantile(z,0.75)}"),
  legend_names = c("Mean", "25th or 75th quantile", "Standard Deviation"),
  add_pointrange = FALSE,
  shade_bar = FALSE
)
}
\arguments{
\item{df}{as data frame of data x,y,facet_row,facet_column,color_bin}

\item{x_label}{as string for x axis}

\item{y_label}{as string for y axis}

\item{color_label}{as string for color axis}

\item{stats_loc}{as string location for the N, FB, GeoMean, can be "left", "center" or "right"}

\item{color_palette}{as string for specific color palette - uses sequential palette from colorspace - default is "Viridis"}

\item{headers}{as string the headers needed for the data must contain: x and y, optional headers rows, columns, and color_bin.  Headers 'rows' and 'columns' refer to the columns used for the facet wrap.  Color bin contains the data used to color the firgure.}

\item{scales_qualifier}{as string Default is "fixed" how scales should be set for facet_wrap.  See: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html for more details}

\item{max_ncol}{as numeric - how many columns to break the facet into - default is 6}

\item{max_nrow}{as numeric - how many rows to break the facet into - default is 6}

\item{set_nrow}{as numieric - OPTIONAL -how many rows, both set_nrow and set_ncol must be included if one is included}

\item{set_ncol}{as numeric -  OPIONAL - how many columns, both set_nrow and set_ncol must be included if one is included}

\item{start_date}{as numeric or date or posixct -  DEFUALT is minium of the x column}

\item{end_date}{as numeric or date or posixct -  DEFUALT is maximum of the x column}

\item{plot_stats}{as string vectory - which stats do you which to plot.  The first plot line will be solid, all others will be dashed.
Other options:  "'min'", "'max'" or other function.}

\item{add_pointrange}{as logical - Default is FALSE error bar will be added to each point with caps}

\item{shade_bar}{as logical - Default is FALSE - errorbar will span the standard deviation of y if TRUE Area will be shaded.}

\item{Date_label}{as string - Default as "%B %d" - format of date axis}
}
\description{
This function will take a data frame as input and create a line plot
}
\details{
stats_loc is the location for the N, FB, GeoMean, can be "left", "center" or "right"
}
\author{
MMB Subroutine for plots
}
```

The heading for one of my functions with the error is located here: (this is what is stored in the /R/ folder)

```
#' @export
#' @title linear line plots
#' @author MMB Subroutine for plots
#' @description This function will take a data frame as input and create a line plot
#' @param df as data frame of data x,y,facet_row,facet_column,color_bin
#' @param x_label as string for x axis
#' @param y_label as string for y axis
#' @param color_label as string for color axis
#' @param stats_loc as string location for the N, FB, GeoMean, can be "left", "center" or "right"
#' @param color_palette as string for specific color palette - uses sequential palette from colorspace - default is "Viridis"
#' @param headers as string the headers needed for the data must contain: x and y, optional headers rows, columns, and color_bin.  Headers 'rows' and 'columns' refer to the columns used for the facet wrap.  Color bin contains the data used to color the firgure.
#' @param scales_qualifier as string Default is "fixed" how scales should be set for facet_wrap.  See: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html for more details
#' @param max_ncol as numeric - how many columns to break the facet into - default is 6
#' @param max_nrow as numeric - how many rows to break the facet into - default is 6
#' @param plot_stats as string vectory - which stats do you which to plot.  The first plot line will be solid, all others will be dashed.
#' Other options:  "'min'", "'max'" or other function.
#' @param set_nrow as numieric - OPTIONAL -how many rows, both set_nrow and set_ncol must be included if one is included
#' @param set_ncol as numeric -  OPIONAL - how many columns, both set_nrow and set_ncol must be included if one is included
#' @param start_date as numeric or date or posixct -  DEFUALT is minium of the x column
#' @param end_date as numeric or date or posixct -  DEFUALT is maximum of the x column
#' @param Date_label as string - Default as "%B %d" - format of date axis
#' @param add_pointrange as logical - Default is FALSE error bar will be added to each point with caps
#' @param shade_bar as logical - Default is FALSE - errorbar will span the standard deviation of y if TRUE Area will be shaded.
#' @details stats_loc is the location for the N, FB, GeoMean, can be "left", "center" or "right"
```

I founds answer to questions where some people had this issue where they needed to escape special characters like the '%'.  As far as I can tell this is not my issue.  Is there another reason for this error?  I've tried changing and removing the @description from my function header without any change in the error statement.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's not a `%` problem? Did you try escaping them in your date label parameter? `\item{Date_label}{as string - Default as "\%B \%d" - format of date axis}`. What version of `roxygen` are you using? Is it older than `7.0.0`?

Comment: Thanks.... I completely missed that spot! (smf)

Comment: But again, it depends on your version of roxygen. In versions later than 7 it should escape the `%` for you. So you might be better off just updating your roxygen version.